# Auto Grid columns, without wrapping to next row

Tags: css, css-grid

I want this 3 boxes to display next to each other, with same `width of 381px`

Their parent is `.boxes` and they are `.box`

[image]

I can do that with the following on parent:

```
.boxes {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 381px);
}
```

**BUT**:

If in future I want to add one more box, I want that `.box` to also be 381px wide.

I don't want to specify number 3, I want it to be **infinite columns of 381px** if new box appears

I want to achieve same result as:

```
grid-template-columns(auto-fit, 381px);
```

But I **don't want them to wrap to next row** if they can't fit.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply make the flow to be column like below:

```css
.boxes {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 381px;
  grid-auto-flow: column; /* this will do the trick */
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.boxes>* {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the following couple lines of code will help you achieve that

```
.boxes {
    display: grid;
    gap: 10px;
    grid-auto-columns: 381px;
    grid-auto-flow: column; 
}
```

The `grid-auto-flow` property defines whether new elements added to the grid will be added as 'implicit rows' or 'implicit columns'. It's default is row, which we want to be column.

The `grid-auto-columns` property is the same as `grid-template-columns`, except that it deals with implicit columns (4th and thereon, since you defined grid to have only 3 columns, the ones that come after those 3 will be implicit columns).